# Cortar pixels da imagem sem distorce-la

Tags: html, css

Bom dia!

Eu quero cortar os lados de uma foto sem distorcer a mesma, é possível?

Por exemplo, tenho essa imagem aqui:

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oeoT.jpg" name="Foto Teste" alt="Foto Teste"/>
```

Ela tem 1200x1200

Eu queria tirar, vamos supor, 400px dos lados (200 de cada lado), ou sejam, quero que ela fique `800 x 1200`

Mas, não quero distorcer imagem nem diminuir, quero manter a mesma coisa so que sem 200px de cada lado. Isso é possível?

## Ilustração:

```css
.imagem
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: red;
    border: 2px solid;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.imagem-menor 
{
    background: #95d6e0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="imagem">
    <div class="imagem-menor"></div>
</div>
```

No caso, a parte vermelha é a que eu quero tirar, a do meio deixar, mas sem distorcer nada.

Comment: Cara editei novamente a resposta com mais uma opção, agora tem 3 formas para vc escolher. Qq coisa comenta lá que te ajudo.

Comment: @hugocslt top velho, vai me ajudar bastante seus exemplos ali! Valeu!

Comment: Tranquilo jovem, sucesso

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Opção 1**

Sim é possível vc pode usar a imagem como um background de uma div que tenha o tamanho que vc quer. Com o estilo `background-position` vc define a posição do seu background dentro da div no caso está centralizado na horizontal e vertical para deixar a mulher no meio e cortar as laterias igualmente

Veja o exemplo. fiz como vc sugeriu, 800x1200

```css
.imagem {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oeoT.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 800px;
    height: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagem"></div>
```

---

**Opção 2**

Outra opção seria colocar o estilo `object-fit: cover` na imagem, assim ela se comporta como um background dentro do tamanho que vc definir na tag `img` Mas isso não é totalmente *crossbrowser* consulte aqui para ver o suporte https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit *(no IE não funciona)*

Veja o exemplo para entender melhor.

```css
.imagem {
    width: 800px;
    height: 1200px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<img class="imagem" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oeoT.jpg" alt="">
```

---

**Opção 3**

Vc pode colocar a imagem dentro de uma `div` com `overflow:hidden` e usar `transform:translateX` para ajusta-la dentro do *container* na posição desejada.

Veja o exemplo. Aqui eu diminui o tamanho proporcionalmente para vc ver que não deforma. Deixei uns comments no código leia.

```css
.imagem {
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden; /* esconde as laterais sobrando da imagem */
}
.imagem img {
    transform: translateX(-14%); /* ajusta a imagem na horizontal na posição que vc quiser*/
    height: 100%; /* deixa a imagem sempre com a altura correta */
}
```

```html
<div class="imagem">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oeoT.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

**DICA:** Apesar de vc não ver o que foi "cortado" essas laterais que estão escondidas fazem parte do arquivo da imagem, então o peso da imagem permanece o mesmo, e na hora da requisição o tamanho do arquivo continuará o mesmo. Considere tratar essas imagens antes de usa-las no site...

Comment: Valeu Hugo! Mas, com a tag img não tem como mesmo ne? É que no sistema aqui(Vtex) tem o lance de zoom também, etc.. Então usam tag img, ai tem o carrossel de imagens também, não teria como eu usar como background acho.

Comment: @LucasCarvalho vou pensar em algo aqui já te falo

Comment: @LucasCarvalho inclui uma edição na minha resposta, mas já adiante que no IE não funciona...